# How to read zero-length file from /sys/fs/cgroup/ in Java?

Tags: java, datainputstream, cgroups

I'd like to read the content of the `/sys/fs/cgroup/` files (eg. `cpuacct.usage`) from Java. I've already implemented the reading algorithm based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/625810/1515439) answer.
The issue is that the cgroup files have 0 length by default. Each of the algorithms listed in the linked answer determines the size of the file before start to read from it, and because the `file.length()` returns 0, it will attempt to read 0 bytes from the file.

Here is the reading algorithm:

```
private String readFile(File file) {
    DataInputStream stream = null;
    String content = "";

    try {
        stream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)));
        final byte[] data = new byte[(int) file.length()]; // new byte[1024] throws exception

        stream.readFully(data);
        content = new String(data);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (stream != null) {
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return content;
}
```

[image: Each file is 0 byte long]

Answer (score 2):

The following approach (using Java NIO) works, even though the OS reports the file length as `0`:

```
String file = "/sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/cpuacct.usage";
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file)));

System.out.println(content); // 972897369764987
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the [IOUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) class in the [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) library.

As the content of those files is text, you can use the `IOUtils.toString` method.

```
String content = IOUtils.toString(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
```